# Play's Hot Reloading and Neo4j Embedded takes too long

Tags: scala, playframework, neo4j, graph-traversal

I am using Neo4j embedded database on a Play/Scala app.  I leaned towards the embedded version because I want to use the Neo4j's Traversal Framework so I can easily create JSON trees using a breadth-first traversal.  The problem with embedding the database is that when my Play application hot-reloads, it restarts the application, whereby my app shuts down the server (otherwise I get a db file lock error).  This is causing 20s browser reloads between edits.  This is especially annoying when editing Play's Twirl html files.

Am I screwed?  Should I hide the calls to the embedded db behind a service?  Is it worth it to do this just for developement?  AFAIK, Neo4j's RESTful service doesn't allow breadth-first traversals.  I'm open to suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that your transactions are all closed (perhaps make it safe by adding a Java shutdown handler that takes care of that), otherwise Neo will wait 20s at shutdown to allow running tx to finish.

```
if (tx != null) tx.close();
db.shutdown();
```

While developing / testing you might also use a in-memory `ImpermanentGraphDatabase` by depending on `org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:test-jar:2.1.5`

See:

- http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html#tutorials-java-embedded-setup-startstop
- http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html

Comment: Dramatic improvement! Closing the transaction alone worked for me.  TY, great product you guys have there :)